# Split a number in chunks of 2 or 3 using regex (python)

Tags: python, regex

Say I have a phone number `+9812345678` and `+99123456789`.
I want to split it in `["+98","12","34","56,"78"]` and `["+99","12","34","56","789"]` i.e: "Start with +99 or +98 and then split in groups of atleast two and max 3"

I have tried something like:

```py
import re
a = "+9812345678"
re.compile("(\+9[98])(\d{2,3})+")
```

which gives

`['', '+98', '78', '']`

that is a bit wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not use `re.split`, use `re.findall`:

```py
re.findall(r'^\+9[98]|\d{2}(?:\d$)?', text)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Zn1QZi/1). **Details**

- `^\+9[98]` - start of string, `+`, `9` and then `9` or `8`
- `|` - or
- `\d{2}` - two digits
- `(?:\d$)?` - an optional sequence of a digit at the end of a string.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/xK6CQj):

```py
import re
texts = ['+9812345678','+99123456789']
for s in texts:
    print(re.findall(r'^\+9[98]|\d{2}(?:\d$)?', s))
# => ['+98', '12', '34', '56', '78']
#    ['+99', '12', '34', '56', '789']
```